# Facebook Pixel 'View Product' Event not tracking

Tags: javascript, facebook, qubit

Having real trouble getting this event configured. I use Qubit.com tag manager and this is the code I have used for the 'view product' event.

This event is not tracking and I don't know why. This is the code -

```
function () {
var _this = this;

console.log('1 FB ViewContent Start');

    var product_ids = [];
    if(universal_variable.transaction.line_items){
        for (var i = 0; i < universal_variable.transaction.line_items.length; i++) {
            product_ids.push(universal_variable.transaction.line_items[i].product.sku_code)
        }
    }

    console.log('2 FB ViewContent Product List Compiled');

    fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
      content_ids: product_ids,
      content_type: 'product',
      value: "" + _this.valueForToken("ORDER_TOTAL"),
  currency: "" + _this.valueForToken("CURRENCY_CODE")
     });

     console.log('3 FB ViewContent Tracked');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling any javascript event action in this code like what are doing with product. Are you on catalog page or viewing a single product after reloading the page(detail page). In both scenario code will be different. Can you paste your full code here.

I am sharing another way to resolve this. You need to put the javascript code before head tag closed.

```
// For single product on the product's detail page
<script>
var _this = this;

    var product_ids = [];
    if(universal_variable.transaction.line_items){
        for (var i = 0; i < universal_variable.transaction.line_items.length; i++) {
            product_ids.push(universal_variable.transaction.line_items[i].product.sku_code)
        }
    }
//Facebook Pixel Code

 !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
                 n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
                 n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
                 t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
                 document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
// FB init 
fbq('init', 'YOUR_PIXEL_ID');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
//FB event
    fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
      content_ids: product_ids,
      content_type: 'product',
      value: "" + _this.valueForToken("ORDER_TOTAL"),
      currency: "" + _this.valueForToken("CURRENCY_CODE")
     });
</script>
```

All event parameter value should be in codes.